# I need a microcontroller with two hardware USART ports

Tags: uart, serial, baudrate

I have a rather peculiar requirement for a project:

I need some sort of microcontroller that has two independent USART interfaces that have to be reconfigurable at runtime.

Let's call them `USART0` and `USART1`.

`USART0` will be used to communicate with a serial interface connected to an existing system.

`USART1` will be talking to a device which will be able to request a higher baud rate, that port would then have to be able to switch to a higher baud rate.

This is what the topology will look like:

```
      System                  Adapter                  Device
------------------      -------------------      ------------------
| system's USART | <--> | USART0 | USART1 | <--> | device's USART |
------------------      -------------------      ------------------
```

The reason for this setup is because we used to have devices connected to the system over USART which only used one baudrate. The systems's USART port (it's actually a TCP/IP adapter/gateway) can only be set up with one baud rate. That baud rate is fixed and cannot be changed while the device is running.

It used to look like this:

```
      System                  Device
------------------      ------------------
| system's USART | <--> | device's USART |
------------------      ------------------
```

We now have a bunch of devices which have an extended capability: they start out with a baud rate of 300bd and are then able to request a higher baud rate (say 9600bd.)

If acknowledged, both devices will switch to a higher baud rate and keep communicating on that one.

The idea is to have an adapter, basically a microcontroller which uses the same fixed baud rate on one USART and is able to switch to a higher baud rate on the other USART.

Since the system's USART must be fixed, the idea is to set it to a fixed bd like 115200bd (which is what we use normally), and have the other USART (`USART1` in my example) start out with 300bd, then switch to a higher baud rate if the device requests a higher rate.

I couldn't figure out if there are microcontrollers which can switch their baud rate without resetting, etc. Also, that requires two independent USART hardware interfaces and I'm not sure which microcontroller to use for just that.

The idea is for that adapter to do a bit of buffering and also translation since data from the system will be sent to the adapter at 115200bd but has to be forwarded to the device with 300bd, as well as data has to be translated to a higher baud rate once the device sends data to the system.

I'm also wondering if I'm completely on the wrong track here, and if there are things like baud translators, etc. available as such.

Comment: Every single microcontroller I've ever used in the last 30 years has been able to change the baud rate on its U(S)ART(s) while running and without resetting the entire device. ARM, PIC, Renesas, Fujitsu, Intel, ... all of them could do that. There's nothing unusual at all in your retirement.

Comment: Spot on @brhans. Meanwhile, are you about to retire or something, was that typo a Freudian slip of what's really on your mind? :-)

Comment: @TonyM autocorrect on Android phones really can read your subconscious mind these days ....

Comment: @brhans, it's not gonna find much in my subconscious to autocorrect, I have enough trouble filling up the conscious bit with something worth it reading these days... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Such microcontrollers exist. Any microcontroller I've ever encountered had run-time adjustable baud rate on its uarts.

Comment: does it work like seamless, while communicating, or does it require some sort of resetting the UART interface? Also, are these things available as some sort of appliance-IC, or does it sounds like something I'd have to actually implement myself?

Comment: @polemon It depends on MCU. Generally it would do no harm to deinit it before changing baud rate, but some support changing it on the fly and some don't. You anyway have to set the baud rate once when MCU boots so it can't be impossible to change it later.

Comment: @polemon is not clear what you think is involved in "reseting the UART interface", or why doing so might be a problem. Typically to change the UART baud rate in an MCU you would disable the UART, set a new baud rate, re-enable the UART. On any MCU made in this century and running at more than a few MHz the process will take a few microseconds at most.

Comment: yeah, in most cases, setting a different baud rate is just changing the value of a divider, i.e. will happen practically instantaneous in terms of CPU clock cycles. In cases where the actual "supersampling" clock needs to be changed, that's always going to be something that's pretty directly derived from a system clock, i.e. will take an extremely short time to settle. (That's easy to see: the whole point of using UARTs is that your clocks don't have to perfectly match. So, no big accuracy and stability when tuning a clock is needed, and things can happen very quickly.)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing peculiar about your requirement.

You just can't find such a feature listed because UART baud rates are reconfigurable to begin with so it does not require special mention about it.

The MCU anyway needs to configure the baud rate in runtime when the software starts up to run the interface at correct speed, nothing prevents from chaging the baud rate later at any point if needed.

You can use any micro with two or more UARTs. It might be hard to find one with only two UARTs these days.

Depending on which MCU you use and how the UART on it works, it may be done on-the fly even if currently a byte transfer is ongoing and it will get corrupted, or it may require to wait until no transfers are in progress and the UART can be disabled while changing the baud rate.

Answer (score -1):

Some MCUs supports auto baud rate detection on their UART receivers. In this case you only need one button for MCU to learn new new baud rate on the next received byte, no need to manually resetting the UART interface. One example is STM32F051, but a lot of others support this feature.

EDIT.
I was partially wrong about how auto baud rate detection works. You could still use it if you can setup your device so that first byte it send is supported by the selected MCU auto baud rate detection algorithm. It could work like this. You press a button on your adapter. After that your device sends correct byte as required by algorithm. After this you can communicate as normal.

Comment: That is incorrect. Sure many MCUs support auto baud rate detection, but detection requires a specific bit pattern to calculate the correct setting, so it can't be used on arbitrary data. Besides this question was not about auto detection but if it is possible to change baud rate.

Comment: @justme you are partialy correct. It can be any character starting with bit at 1. But yeah, I read RM too fast and though it could be any pattern.

Comment: There are different modes of operation even in different STM32 MCUs, there is no single mode and it can be selectable.